# What will be the possible major product(s) on heating this primary alcohol i.e. 9-fluorenylmethanol with (conc) H2SO4?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, alcohols

[image]

When the above compound is heated with (conc.) $\ce{H2SO4}$ the $\ce{OH}$ will probably be protonated and it will leave, producing a carbocation. After that possibly there will be a hydride shift. Now, after this step what could be the possibilities. I was thinking of ring expansion (which could potentially form **phenanthrene**) but again I doubt that a negative charge on a $sp^2$ carbon of the benzene ring would attack the positive charge after C-C bond cleavage. Or another possibility is formation of a double bond to form a structure like:

[image]

Which is the correct (major) product formed?

Comment: Ring expansion is possible and we get  an aromatic compound I suppose which is quite stable....

Comment: @SurajS For ring expansion we need to form a negative charge on the benzene ring which has to potentially attack the formed carbocation due to leaving of the $\ce{OH2+}$ group. Is that feasible?

Comment: I think this process favors thermodynamics, Phenanthrene might be the major product...

Comment: Sorry I don't get why - ve charge on the benzene has to be formed... Isn't it th 3° carbon making way for the rearrangement so that 1° carbocation stabilizes to 2°?

Comment: Which  "$1°$ carbocation stabilizes to $2^o$" are you talking about? I can't understand. Can you draw it and show? @SurajS

Comment: @SurajS A negative charge is formed on the benzene ring when the C-C bond between $\beta$ carbon and the $\gamma$ carbon of the $\ce{OH}$ group cleaves. That negative charge can attack the $1^o$ $\alpha$ carbon so that it can expand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I feel is that forming phenanthrene would be possible because of its high stability due to resonance. Initially, $\ce{-OH2}$ leaves out forming a 1°carbocation. Now the $\ce{\beta C-\gamma C}$ cleaves so as to make way for the better 2°carbocation which is also thermodynamically favourable. [image]

Comment: Related: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/231517152_Dehydration_of_9-Fluorenylcarbinol_a_New_Synthesis_of_Phenanthrene